Wacom buttons are getting stuck and crashing Ubuntu 24.04.1, any advice on how to fix?
I have recently upgraded to Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS. I have a Wacom Cintiq 13HD tablet, and use Krita for drawing. The shortcut keys keep getting "stuck" - e.g. I click a button mapped to "ctrl+z (undo)" and it starts spamming "undo" until I reach the start of undo history.
It's intermittent, I usually get about 10 minutes with everything working before it happens. Pressing the same key on my keyboard will cancel/un-stick the bound key - but then the tablet keys stop working entirely. Disconnecting and re-connecting the tablet sometimes works, but more often crashes, kicking me back to the login screen after a few seconds of black, with no applications running. I've tried upgrading to a newer version of Krita, but it seems to make no difference. I've experienced this issue with no other applications running (besides Krita). I haven't experienced this issue just having the tablet plugged in and turned on - it's only when using the buttons.
I'd guess it's an issue with the Wacom drivers. I probably have mucked about with a config file or something in the past to get it working, unfortunately I don't remember how, I just know that it was working before the upgrade.
Does anyone have advice on how to debug/fix this?

sudo journalctl -u systemd-logind would be a good start to understand if the behavior is due to the ACPI event being spammed

@kos Unfortunately I don't see anything helpful in the logs, thanks for the pointer though.

Have you looked into this? https://github.com/linuxwacom/input-wacom it appears as though these could be the drivers shipped with Ubuntu itself. I haven't looked at the changelog, however since that appear to be the source (and by any chance the version hosted on github right now will be more, if not way more, updated than whatever you have running right now), you could try and compile / install them, it's probably worth a shot
